# Sum a list column of matrices in a data.frame by grouping factor

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a `dataframe` where one of the columns is a list containing a matrix for each row, defining a transition matrix for that observation.

```
library(tidyverse)
m <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
d <- data_frame(g = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'),
                m = rep(list(m), 6))
```

This looks like:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
      g             m
   <chr>        <list>
1     a <int [2 × 2]>
2     a <int [2 × 2]>
3     b <int [2 × 2]>
4     b <int [2 × 2]>
5     b <int [2 × 2]>
6     c <int [2 × 2]>
```

I want to get out list of two matrices, `a` and `b` that are the sum of all the matrices for each respective grouping factor. I need this method to generalize to an arbitrary number of groups, because I will not know the number of grouping factors in advance.

I have tried `by_slice` and `do`, but all I can manage to output is a sum of all matrices, or a sum of either the `a` or `b` matrices alone -- not bound in a single group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by nesting the matrices within groups (with tidyr's `nest`), which creates a list column that contains lists of matrices. You can then use purrr's `map` and `reduce` to sum up the matrices within each group's list:

```
results <- d %>%
  nest(-g) %>%
  mutate(summed = map(data, ~ reduce(.$m, `+`)))
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      g             data        summed
  <chr>           <list>        <list>
1     a <tibble [2 × 1]> <int [2 × 2]>
2     b <tibble [3 × 1]> <int [2 × 2]>
3     c <tibble [1 × 1]> <int [2 × 2]>
```

The `summed` column will have the matrices added up within each group.

---

If you wanted to turn this into a named list with items a/b/c of matrices, you could do:

```
lst <- results$summed
names(lst) <- results$g
lst
```

or alternatively:

```
results %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  spread(g, summed)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `group_by`, `summarise`, and `reduce`:

```
m_sum <- function(l) {
  reduce(l, `+`) %>% list()
}

group_by(d, g) %>%
  summarise(m_sum = m_sum(m)) %>%
  select(m_sum) %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```